# How to mock a interface and its method via gmock

Tags: c++, googlemock

Below is the sample code. When I tried to mock Circle it is giving an error as "Error   C2027   use of undefined type 'testing::internal::Function<HRESULT (int, int)>'

```
class foo: public IUnknown
{
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Circle(int x, int y) = 0;
.....
.....
};
```

To mock this I tried something like this:

```
class fooMock: public foo
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD2(Circle, HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE(int x, int y));
    
};
```

Comment: remove `STDMETHODCALLTYPE` from interface, you do not need that. This is used to define calling convention of external dll API, so you do not have to apply this to interface.

Comment: I have tried without that also..didn't work

Answer (score 2):

It is good that you are hiding dependency behind an interface. Its good nice practice.

Now apparently your interface separates you from windows specific header files.
This is also very good, but it leads to your error. Error says that `HRESULT` symbol is unknown.

Quick dirty fix is to include respective Windows header: `winnt.h`.

Proper fix would be replace `HRESULT` with something which will represent success/error result. It can be `bool` (equal to `result >= 0`) it can be `long` or it can be some class representing error/success. Choice depends on how your business logic handles those errors?

Side note:

Note that `STDMETHODCALLTYPE` is used to define calling convention of function. It has no impact on application logic. It impacts ABI of function.
So when you hiding function with modified ABI behind interface you can ignore this modification and keep standard ABI for interface.

Extra note:

`gmock` some time ago has introduced more handy way to define mocks, which makes them easier to write manually (there is also a tool which can generate them from interfaces):

```cpp
class fooMock: public foo
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(long, Circle, (int x, int y), ());
    // last argument can contain: "(const override noexcept)" and similar stuff
};
```